# Where does "patching through" come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases, meaning-in-context

Where does "patching through" come from?

And what did it originally mean?

Usage: "I'm patching through a call from Mr. X"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The original telephone switchboards were literally  [patch boards](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patchboard): the caller and callee were physically connected with a wire (patch cable) to form a circuit.

[image]

Photo from [here](http://pickeringbrookheritagegroup.com/infrastructure7.html).

Answer (score 5):

Macmillan Dictionary has an entry for *[patch through](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/patch-through)*:

> **patch someone through** to allow someone speaking to you on a phone or radio to speak to someone else
>   *I’m just patching you through now.*

Dictionary.com's 18th definition of [patch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patch) also has that meaning.

The etymology is directly related to the terms [@Useless](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/where-does-patching-through-come-from#comment117646_61639) commented (and then answered) about: *patching through* used to mean connecting the two calls with a [patch cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_cable) ([often called](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=patch%20cable,patch%20cord&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) a *[patch cord](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patch%20cord)* or *[patchcord](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patch+cord)*) on a [patchboard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patchboard) (which is [often called](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=patch%20panel,patchboard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) a *[patch panel](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/patch_panel.html)*).  The phrase still applies, though, even if there isn't a physical patch panel.

The etymology of the usage of *patch* in this context is probably from using temporary connections, as opposed to permanently wired ones.

Comment: Old telephone exchanges (switchboards) were literally [patch boards](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patchboard): the caller and the callee were physically connected with a wire (or patch cable) to form a circuit.

Comment: @Useless, you should turn that into an answer, it is spot on

Answer (score 2):

To take it a little further back, they were called patch boards, I believe, because they were used for temporary connections in some electrical systems, so they were a patch to make something work for a while, before, sometimes, the system was hard wired.